CORS policy problem...How can I solve it?
I've created a simple Rest application using Spring. When I try to enter the API using Angular I got this error
Access to XMLHttpRequest at '``http://localhost:9595/api/luoghi/all``' from origin '``http://localhost:4200``' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
How can I solve this?
These are the files:
Rest Controller
package it.ootareg.controllers;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import it.ootareg.entities.Luoghi;
import it.ootareg.services.LuoghiService;
import jakarta.transaction.Transactional;

@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/luoghi")
@Transactional
public class LuoghiController {

    @Autowired
    private LuoghiService lService;
    
    @GetMapping("/all")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Luoghi>> getAll(){
        
        List<Luoghi> luoghi = lService.findAll();
        
        return new ResponseEntity<>(luoghi, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/find/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Luoghi> getById(@PathVariable("id") Long id){
        
        Luoghi luoghi = lService.findLuoghiById(id );
        
        return new ResponseEntity<>(luoghi, HttpStatus.OK); 
    }
    
    @PostMapping("/add")
    public ResponseEntity<Luoghi> add(@RequestBody Luoghi luogo){
        
        Luoghi newLuogo = lService.addLuoghi(luogo);
        
        return new ResponseEntity<>(newLuogo, HttpStatus.CREATED); 
    } 
    
    @PutMapping("/update")
    public ResponseEntity<Luoghi> update(@RequestBody Luoghi luogo){
        
        Luoghi newLuogo = lService.updateLuoghi(luogo);
        
        return new ResponseEntity<>(newLuogo, HttpStatus.OK); 
    
    }
     
    @GetMapping("/delete/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> delete (@PathVariable("id") Long id){
        
        lService.deleteLuoghi(id);
        
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK); 
    }
    
    
}

Web Config
package it.ootareg.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
                .allowedMethods(HttpMethod.GET.name(),
                        HttpMethod.POST.name(),
                        HttpMethod.PUT.name(),
                        HttpMethod.DELETE.name())
                .allowedHeaders(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE,
                        HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION);
    }
}

Rest Service
package it.ootareg.services;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import it.ootareg.entities.Luoghi;
import it.ootareg.exceptions.UserNotFoundException;
import it.ootareg.repo.LuoghiRepo;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Service
public class LuoghiService {

    @Autowired
    private LuoghiRepo repo;
    
    public Luoghi addLuoghi(Luoghi luogo) {
        
        return repo.save(luogo);
    }
    
    public List<Luoghi> findAll(){
        
        return repo.findAll();
    }
    
    public Luoghi updateLuoghi(Luoghi luogo) {
        
        return repo.save(luogo);
    }
    
    public void deleteLuoghi(Long id) {
        
         repo.deleteLuoghiById(id);
    }
    
    public Luoghi findLuoghiById(Long id) {
        
        return repo.findLuoghiById(id).orElseThrow(
                ()->new UserNotFoundException("Luogo " + id +" non trovato"));
    }
    
    
}

Angular Service
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Luoghi } from './Luoghi';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LuoghiService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  private apiUrl = "http://localhost:9595/api";

  public getLuoghi() : Observable<Luoghi[]> {
    return this.http.get<Luoghi[]>(`${this.apiUrl}/luoghi/all`)
  }

  public addLuogo(luogo : Luoghi) : Observable<Luoghi> {
    return this.http.post<Luoghi>(`${this.apiUrl}/luoghi/add`, luogo)
  }

  public updateLuogo(luogo : Luoghi) : Observable<Luoghi> {
    return this.http.put<Luoghi>(`${this.apiUrl}/luoghi/update`, luogo)
  }

  public deleteLuogo(luogoID : number) : Observable<void> {
    return this.http.delete<void>(`${this.apiUrl}/luoghi/delete/${luogoID}`)
  }
   
}


app module
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { LuoghiService } from './luoghi.service';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [LuoghiService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }

I've tried these things but the error remain, what am I missing?
I've tried differents option that I've found here on Stackoverflow but none of them is working.
I've tried even to put the actual link in the annotation ("localhost:4200") but neither that has worked.

Are you enabling authentication or authorization that uses cookies? If so, you need to add the following configuration in your webConfig: allowCredentials(true).

Added but still the same


Are you enabling authentication or authorization that uses cookies?
If this is the case, you need to do two things.


add the following configuration in your webConfig: allowCredentials(true)
set withCredentials property to true in angular request to give permission


Added aaand Same :(

I may have a try if you can share your repo :). looks strange
